# iOS build and distribute a private framework

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks

I have a problem, I'm developing for work a Swift private framework and we have to distribute it.
The problem is how to build it, Xcode by default split the build for the simulator and the build for the physical device.
Googling I find how to merge this two different build, but int this case I have problem when I try to upload to the app store an app with the framework inside.
Do you know how Fabric does?

Thanks you all!

Comment: Why not to distribute it as a cocoapods private pod?. Also there is no problem having a framework in your project. Can you explain what is the error you are seeing ?